# How to align text content with image in a row bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a specific display depending on whether I have an image or not in a row bootstrap.

I want when I have an image and text content, I can have in the same row for a column size 4 my image and right my text content with a column size of 8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsnpT.png)

According to the display below and if the image is not there I can have instead of the image the content.

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/b0f7cc" title="picture" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div>
                textdffjjfjfjfj
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

use align-items-center as class in parent div. here is the snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container ">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/b0f7cc" title="picture" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div>
                textdffjjfjfjfj
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use align-items-center as class in parent div. here is the snippet

and if you want to remove image then you have to add style of some specific height so it will align all items in center according to the height.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container ">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/b0f7cc" title="picture" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div>
                textdffjjfjfjfj
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```